# Automatically set end time when start time is changed

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I am using [daterangepicker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) to select the start time and end time for an appointment. Currently, when the start time is changed the end time becomes the same.

[image]

I would like to have the end time automatically increment by an hour once the start time is altered.

Here's my code

```
$(function () {
    $('input[name="appt_time"]').daterangepicker({
        timePicker: true,
        timePicker24Hour: true,
        timePickerIncrement: 5,
        timePickerSeconds: false,
        locale: {
            format: 'HH:mm'
        }
    }).on('show.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        picker.container.find(".calendar-table").hide();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late and not so elegant, but since Daterangepicker has limited options, I build this solution:

```
$('.calendar.left').on('change', function(ev) {
    // Checks if left hour select (startDate) was changed
    if(ev.target.className === 'hourselect') {
        // Increases endDate by 1 hour
        $('input[name="appt_time"]').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(moment($('input[name="appt_time"]').data('daterangepicker').startDate).add(1, 'hours'))
        // Updates view and select
        $('input[name="appt_time"]').data('daterangepicker').updateView()
        $($('.hourselect')[1]).val($('input[name="appt_time"]').data('daterangepicker').endDate.format('HH'))
    }
});
```